# Can Blender be used for business purposes?

Tags: licensing

Can the free version of Blender be added to a new software by incorporating all the dev tools of it into this new software and then be given away for installation to the common public? Any way how that can be done legally for business?

Comment: what you mean incorporating? (you can't link dynamically) What you mean by dev tools? You can sell GPL software. see: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/47032/can-i-use-gpl-software-in-a-commercial-application

Comment: Here's a link to the [license at the blender website:](https://www.blender.org/about/license/)

Answer (score -1):

Blender is GPL licensed - and subject to all the terms of GPL licensing (barring some components of it).  For more information, look here: https://www.blender.org/about/license/

Comment: Which means that yes, you can use all of Blender's source code for anything you like (including commercial products), but if you distribute any product that uses source code from Blender, you must also release the source code of your own product.

Comment: That implies the direct answer, but it doesn't answer the question directly...