# Terms of use for procedural generation/simulation?

Tags: smoke-simulation, fluid-simulation, ocean-simulation, procedural

does anybody know if you need to pay royalties if you were to use something like an object with blender's ocean modifier or smoke simulator in a paid game?

Comment: Blender is Free and Open Source software, that means that not only you are free to use it in any way you see fit, even payed or commercial, as long as you keep the sources available, the content produced is also yours, commercial or otherwise. See https://www.blender.org/about/license

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48880/can-blender-be-used-for-business-purposes/48883#48883